# typo3 setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored not work

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to access the database field `endtime`.
According to many sources, I have collected the following:

```
public function findAllForm() {
$query = $this->createQuery();
$querySettings = $query->getQuerySettings();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(true);
$query->getQuerySettings()->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(array("endtime"));
$query->setQuerySettings($querySettings);
return $query->execute();
}
```

Then call it as follows:

```
$allItems = $this->FormYouRepository->findAllForm();
```

If I then output via var_dump, this object will not be listed at all.

My typo3-version is 6.2

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check also the `storagePid` of your plugin. But you can call the `$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);` to ignore the `storagePid`